# Seleccionar ciertos workflows

Tags: informatica-power-center

Buen dia a todos, antes que nada gracias por haberme aceptado. Ayudenme (por favor), quiero sacar un extracto de ciertos workflows desde IPC. No tengo acceso a "exportar metadatos", solo tengo acceso al workflow monitor y workflow manager. O de que forma puedo desde el workflow monitorseleccionar rapidamente (hotkeys) un flujo junto con todas sus caracteristicas.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿La [documentación oficial](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/284340?language=en_US) te sirve?

Comment: No tenga esa opcion habilitada. Alguna otra forma?. Gracias

Comment: Alfabravo buen dia. Al momento de exportar el workflow este incluira los campos: start time y completion time de la ultima ejecucion?. Lo que pasa es que yo quiero comparar el tiempo de ejecucion con otro archivo que es el inventario de workflows. Gracias